# Error in rstudio coding

Tags: rstudio, corpus

I running my corpus in Rstudio, it runs first and second line coding but generating error on third row.

```
s<- Corpus(DirSource("C:/Users/mazhar/Documents/Sindhicorpus", pattern = "*.txt")
           Word <- wordcloud(words = names(term.freq), 
                             freq = term.freq, min.freq = 1, random.order = F, colors = brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))
```

The error is

```
Error: unexpected ',' in "freq = term.freq,"
```

Comment: Missing ) after `Corpus(DirSource("...",pattern="*txt")` ?

Comment: What is term? It must be assigned value of frequencies i think